# Redirect debug and STDOUT to different files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect

Is there a way to redirect my debug output to a file and normal STDOUT on screen.

```
$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo HAI
echo BYE

$ sh -x test1.sh
+ echo HAI
HAI
+ echo BYE
BYE
```

I want to redirect the debug output to file and normal output on the screen.

```
$ sh -x test1.sh >file1
+ echo HAI
+ echo BYE
```

But I can redirect the output to a file and ending the debug output on screen.

Comment: debug output from `-x` goes to stderr. You can redirect stderr to a file as shown by @Tichodroma

Comment: What if your script writes to stderr and would like to separate debug output from the output of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used alias to give the complete command and using the following way

```
$ alias mytest='sh -x test1.sh 2>out.test'
$ mytest
HAI
BYE
$ cat out.test
+ echo HAI
+ echo BYE
```

Thanks every one..

Comment: Did any of the answers help you so you can accept it? How about upvoting helpful answers?

Answer (score 3):

Use `2>`:

```
$ sh -x test1.sh 2> /dev/null
HAI
BYE
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/1907906

Answer (score 2):

Default file descriptors on linux system are:

```
stdin - 0
stdout - 1
stderr - 2
```

to redirect to file,

```
sh test1.sh 1> file
```

to redirect error(stderr) to console(stdout)

```
sh test1.sh 2>&1
```